# Form submission refreshes page instead of redirecting

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, forms

I have the following form in my `ReceivingController` `Index.cshtml` view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Grv"))
{
    @Html.TextBox("grvNumber")
    <input type="submit" value="search" />
}
```

As I understand it, this should redirect to `Details.cshtml` of my `GrvController`, passing in `grvNumber` as input.

However, when I submit the form, I am simply taken back to the same page (`Receiving/Index`).

I suspect this may have something to do with my routing, but I can't work out what is going wrong.

#### RouteConfig

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Receiving",
    url: "receiving",
    defaults: new { controller = "Receiving", action = "Index" }
    );
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ViewGrv",
    url: "receiving/{grvNumber}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Grv", action = "Details" }
    );
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ViewPallet",
    url: "receiving/{grvNumber}/{palletSequence}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Pallet", action = "Details" }
    );
```

#### GrvController

```
public class GrvController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Details(string grvNumber)
    {
        var access = new Access();
        var grvData = access.GetGrvData(grvNumber);

        var grv = new Grv(grvData);
        Session["grv"] = grv;

        return View(grv);
    }
}
```

I tried adding `[HttpPost]` to the `GrvController` `Details` method, and also added the `FormMethod.post` parameter to `BeginForm`, but the behaviour is exactly the same.

If I navigate manually to the url `../receiving/8`, then I see the correct `Grv` `Details` page, but I need to see this page after submitting the `Receiving` form.

I can see from setting break points that submiting the form never reachers `GrvController`

Any advice is much appreciated, and let me know if I can post more details.

Comment: Does the `Details` action accepts a string parameter in its method?

Comment: @Sajal It does indeed

Comment: The `Details` method needs to be marked with `[HttpPost]`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I added `[HttpPost]` but it still has the same behaviour

Comment: Are you saying that after adding`[HttpPost]` it does not hit the `Details` method of `GrvController`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke That is correct

Comment: try to use this in your view @using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Grv", FormMethod.Post)

Comment: @Vishal Just tried that Vishal but I am seeing the same result.. I don't understand what is going on!

Comment: What is the method that initially generated the view? And your 1st `Default` route is odd. Its normally `url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",` and needs to be after the other more specific routes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke That did it, thanks for the help! I don't really understand why that solves the problem though, as `HomeController` is not even involved in my issue

Comment: `HomeController` has nothing to do with it (`Home` and `Index` are just the default controller and action when no segments are provided)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your RouteConfig file

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Strange enough this led me to my answer, but I just set the `controller` param in `defaults` to `"Home"` instead of `"Receiving"` (as that is the actualy default page), and that seems to have worked for some reason

Comment: That cannot work unless its **after** the other routes

Comment: @StephenMuecke Copying the route that Vishal posted, but replacing `Receiving` with `Home` works even at the top of the file

Comment: @Bassie, No it will not - it will cause other issues (for example your `ViewGrv` route will never work)

Comment: yes @Bassie sorry for mismatch names that i forget to change name of default controller.
I edit my answer.

Comment: @StephenMuecke You are absolutely right, noticing now that including this at the top has ruined all my other routes! Will have to look into that, thanks again for the help